# Task manager closing event not firing

Tags: vb.net, events, formclosing

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.TaskManagerClosing Then
        e.Cancel = True
        IO.File.Create(Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\TEST.TXT").Dispose()
    End If
End Sub
```

When I close this from Task Manager, it's not firing the event for the task manger closing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when closing the form from the task manager that's i was close from end process
and the events for the end task so if you end the form from the end process it will not exits if you end it from the end task it will exit